# How to disable media queries and viewport in iframe

Tags: iframe, media-queries, viewport

I'm loading iframes for a special application and need a way to disable the responsive coding (viewport and media queries) in all iframes.

Is there a simple way to do this? Let's say applying an ID to the element was out of the question (since it's from another domain).